# Dynamically toggle formatoptions based on input

Tags: indentation, autocmd, formatting, comments

**Question:** Is there a way to control the indentation + comment leader input, when adding a new line?

**Details:** I am trying to set `formatoptions-=cro` when inserting a new line (in specific syntax region). I tried using the autocommands `InsertEnter` and `InsertCharPre`, but both are too generic for my use case and I cannot figure out how to only operate on entering an `<Enter>` when in insert and `o`/`O` when in normal mode.

(`InsertCharPre` does not trigger on new line insertions, and `InsertEnter` also triggers on typing `a`/`A`/`i`/`I`.) What am I missing? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. :)

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, that my intention is to dynamically add/suppress a comment-continuation insertion on new line insertions (depending on the syntax region).

Comment: If there hadn't been an option to handle this per your answer then rather than try to detect newline insertions I think a promising route would be `'indentexpr`'. You could have a function decide whether to pass control to regular indentation methods or to swallow it. Would require a bit of work to detect everything but it's less hacky than newline fishing, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** I was looking for `:set comments+=f:{string}`.

**Details:** My usecase is, that every time I have the following style starting comment (in a javascript file) and I type `<Enter>`/`o`/`O` it should not yield an auto-indented + auto-commented next line on enter:

```
/*::<Enter>
 * <-- I wanted to suppress this
```

The solution to this was to `:set comments+=f:/*::`, which sets the comment to not be continued with any `mb:{string}` comments on the next line. See `:help comments` for further details.

**Note:** If you still have an answer to "How do I trigger a function on adding a new line?" feel free to answer. ✌️